# How to render only the div from controller action in mvc.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
I have used PartialView but it renders the whole view after success full ajax post
This is my view
 my ul which i want to update
<ul id="ULdinnerlist">
    @* my foreach loop*@
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <li>  Title : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)<br />
              EventDate : @Html.Encode(item.EventDate.ToShortDateString()+ " @ " + item.EventDate.ToShortTimeString()) 
              <p>Description : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p><br />
               HostedBy : <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HostedBy)</b> (@item.ContactPhone)<br />
        </li>
    }


</ul>
```

my ajax route link
    @Ajax.RouteLink(">>>",new { page = Model.PageIndex + 1 },new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ULdinnerlist" })

```
ON controller: my action for reindering 

public ActionResult Index(int? Page)
        {
            int PageSize = 5;
            IQueryable<Dinner> dines = from dine in db.Dinners orderby dine.EventDate select dine;
            var paginatedDinners = new PagingList<Dinner>(dines, Page ?? 0, PageSize);

            checking ajax post and rendering accordingly    
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView(paginatedDinners);
            }
            return View(paginatedDinners);
        }
```

Problem is it renders the whole view when i do the paging.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return different information in response to your AJAX request, you need to render a different view,  simply returning PartialView(same_view_name) won't actually do anything.

Alternatively, within your current view check to see whether the request is an AJAX request and then selectively render the relevant sections.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of retuning View you should return PartailView Or string as return type of partial view is MvcHtmlString.

In controller

```
public string SomeAction(int? Page)
        {
            int PageSize = 5;
            IQueryable<Dinner> dines = from dine in db.Dinners orderby dine.EventDate select dine;
            var paginatedDinners = new PagingList<Dinner>(dines, Page ?? 0, PageSize);

           return RenderPartialViewToString("PartialViewName",paginatedDinners )
        }

protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

you should use different action to handle Ajax request, as it's return type is different so  can not be use it in "Index".

by passing partail view name and it's model to **RenderPartialViewToString** method it will return you RenderHtml of Partial.

```
//actionLink
    @Ajax.RouteLink(">>>","SomeAction",new { page = Model.PageIndex + 1 },new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ULdinnerlist",InsertionMode =InsertionMode.Replace })
```

Comment: Thanks shivkumar 
so it is compulsory to create a partial view for that particular section? we cannot use that section of view in the same view itself

Comment: yes because as you call the action through Ajax so it's return type either string or JSON. if call the view then request is map through RouteCollection so it will refresh you page at each request.

Comment: This is terrible advice. You are completely destroying the MVC abstraction by rendering your view into a string. Additionally, it will be more difficult to write unit tests using this method.